# subcribeOn() io.reactivex.Scheduler in Observable cannot be applied to rx.Scheduler

Tags: java, android, system.reactive

I have about 4 other .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) but this is the only one that doesn't work

```
mSearchBarString = PublishSubject.create();
    return mSearchBarString
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

The only difference is that others use

```
Observable<JSONObject> jsonObjectObservable = Observable.just(data);
```

something like this while this one uses PublishSubject.create();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the wrong import for PublishSubject that was the problem